# Sporadic IE8 page loading problem

Tags: internet-explorer-8, pageload

When accessing my web app in IE8, sometimes the page won't finish loading. I'll see "(1 item remaining) Waiting for http://localhost:8080/..."

The problem is very sporadic as I can navigate through my web application hitting pages dozens of time before this problem arises. I've only seen the problem in IE8, but I can't say for certain that it doesn't happen in other browsers too.

The application is written using JSF with Richfaces 3.3.3 and JBoss Seam 2.2. The DOCTYPE is XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

I've used HttpWatch and Fiddler2 to see if a request is hanging, but I never see any requests waiting to finish.

Has anyone come across this problem too? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question, but I figured I would document my solution here and hopefully it will help someone in the future. I had the same issue and finally stumbled upon this discussion on the RichFaces comunity: https://community.jboss.org/thread/170380. I basically downloaded Prototype 1.6.1 and replaced the previous version contained in the framework.pack.js file in the richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar (org/ajax4jsf/framework.pack.js) with the newer version and voila! No more hanging and "(1 item remaining)" nonsense.

On a side note, we are running a patched version of the RichFaces 3.3.3 with Seam 2.2.2 that not only includes the Prototype fix but also the fix for IE9 and Sarissa: https://community.jboss.org/thread/156720. Hope this helps somebody.